# Android Studio does not recognize .mp4 file type, nor is it listed as a file type in Settings

Tags: android, android-studio, types, mp4, file-type-associations

I have tried importing several different .mp4 video files into the raw folder created under res. Android Studio does not recognize the file type.  Every .mp4 file has a "?" in a box to the left of the file name.   In fact, in the file types settings, neither mp4 or mp3 are listed as possible choices.

When I try to associate the file with an application, there is not suitable application listed.  When I click on the file within raw, it plays with no problem with Windows Media Player.How do I get Android Studio to recognize the .mp4 file type so that it can play in my app??

Comment: Android Studio recognizing it has nothing to do with playing it in the app.  Whether that works or not depends on if your device has the correct codec.

Comment: No emulator or portable device can play app.  However, the file can be played by clicking on it in raw through the PC media player.  Minimally, shouldn't the emulators have the correct codec?  Would that keep Android Studio from recognizing the .mp4 file type by not having the correct codec?  Mp4 nor Mp3 are listed in A.S. file types.

Comment: Entirely depends on what codec you used to encode your file.  No OS has every codec ever created.

Comment: And raw files are just binary data, so AS doesn't need to know it's type

Comment: So, do I need to re-render the video file using different codec?

Comment: There are enough apps in play store that can play mp4's. So install one. An Android device by default cannot display so many files but then the market saves you. And why bother about some question marks in Android Studio.